# How to modify jQuery Carousel to display vertical instead of horizontal

Tags: jquery, carousel

I'm trying to get this jQuery Feature Carousel - http://www.bkosborne.com/jquery-feature-carousel to display vertical instead of horizontal. I tried playing around with the CSS by altering the width and height of the #carousel-container and #carouse it but didn’t really work properly (the effects display in one continuous line instead of rotating). I think it would require some editing in the jquery.featureCarousel.js file but I'm not sure what to edit. Hoping someone can help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In Horizontal carousel menu JS there is one variable `direction:"horizontal"`

so i think you need to change `direction:"vertical"`

Just Try it...may be needful.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks, I have tried this but it didn't work. I've contacted the orginal developer so hopfully there's a solution.